# Java Search for a sub list from a list with many criteria

Tags: java, list, search

I want to make a search method from a list of Restaurants. The user has a GUI form and complete only the fields that he wants.
I made a method meetsCriteria to check if this Restaurant exist. It works but not in all cases.

```
public class RestaurantList {
    private ArrayList<Restaurant> _restaurants = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
        RestaurantList selRest;

        RestaurantList searchRestaurant(String name, String area, String phone, String category)
                {
                    selRest = new RestaurantList();
                    for (int i=0; i< _restaurants.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if(_restaurants.get(i).meetsCriteria(name, area, phone, category))
                        {
                            selRest.addRestaurant(_restaurants.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                    return this.selRest;
                }

public class Controller {


    //this is list with all Restaurants
    static RestaurantList restList = new RestaurantList();
    //this is list with the result of the search.

    public static RestaurantList selList; // selectedList


    public void addRestaurant (Restaurant rest)
    {
        restList.addRestaurant(rest);
    }

    public  void searchCriteria(String name, String area, String phone, String category)
    {

        int size = restList.getRestaurants().size();
        for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
            selList = restList.searchRestaurant(name, area, phone, category);

    }  
}

public class Restaurant {
        private String _name;
    private String _address;
    private String _phoneNum;
        private Area _area;

        public boolean meetsCriteria(String name, String area, String phone, String category)
        {
            if( this._name.equals(name) && this._area.getArea().equals(area) && this._phoneNum.equals(phone) && this._category.equals(category) )
            {
                return true;


            }
            if ( name.equals("") && area.equals(this._area.getArea()) && phone.equals("") && category.equals("") )
            {
                return true;


            }
            if ( name.equals("") && area.equals(this._area.getArea()) && phone.equals(this._phoneNum) && category.equals("") )
            {
                return true;


            }
            if (name.equals("") && area.equals(this._area.getArea()) && phone.equals("") && category.equals(this._category) )
            {
               return true; 


            }
            if ( area.equals(this._area.getArea()) && phone.equals("") && category.equals("") )
            {
                int index = this._name.indexOf(name);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    return true; 
                }else return false;


            }
            if (area.equals(this._area) && category.equals(this._category) )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Not in all cases = doesn't return all of the restaurants that meet the criteria? Please post an example with input and output so we can have a better understanding.

Comment: I have a list with restaurant and I want to find some of them for example all with the same category or same category and same area.

Comment: I checked which fields are null  and I want to do the search with the completed fields. Inside the Restaurant I do this check.

Comment: Okay, and in what way does this code not currently do that?

Comment: I move my suggestion from answer to comment, since some annonymous users are Troll-like enough to downvote and skip the corresponding comment (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes). Remove your `return false` statements, add a unique return false in the end and, if you will, refactor your code to make it more comprehensible by adding comments and extracting the comparation logic to attribute-related methods.

Comment: If I put two and more restaurant with area "new york" and one of them has also category "indian" and then I do searchCriteria("","new york", "","") I will take back these two. If I do searchCriteria ("","new york","","Indian") I will take null

Comment: Gamb return false is required to compile the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by writing a unit test for the "meetsCriteria" method so that you can easily see which conditions pass and which fail.

For example:

```
assertTrue(myRestaurant.meetsCriteria("nandos", "new york", "0124536", "tasty"));
```

Ps., I would probably change your "searchRestaurant" into something like this:

```
List<Restaurant> searchRestaurant(List<Restaurant> allRestaurants, String name, String area, String phone, String category) {
    List<Restaurant> matches = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    for (Restaurant restaurant : allRestaurants) {
        if (restaurant.meetsCriteria(name, area, phone, category)) {
            matches.addRestaurant(allRestaurants.get(i));
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your meetsCriteria() method seems a little bit complicated and misses a lot of combination of criteria that are specified or not. Since you have 4 parameters and each parameter can be specified or not, you have 16 (2^4) possible different cases. Obviously, you code doesn't contain that many. The number of possible cases doubles for each field you add to this Restaurant class. You must find a way to avoid this combinatory explosion by making sure that you only need to add one test for each field.

Can I suggest you try this way:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private String _name;
    private String _address;
    private String _phoneNum;
    private Area _area;

    public boolean meetsCriteria(String name, String area, String phone, String category)
    {
        if ( !name.equals("") && !name.equals(this._name) && this._name.indexOf(name) < 0){
            // name has been specified and does not match
            return false;
        }

        if(!areas.equals("") && this._aread.getArea().equals(area)){
            // area has been specified and does not match
            return false;
        }

        // ... snip ...
        // do the same kind of thing for phone and category
        // ... snip ...

        // At this point, all the criteria that have been specified by the user match,
        // and all the criteria that haven't been specified have been ignored.
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can probably do all that in one huge if() statement, but that would probably not be very readable.

Or even better, you can extract the matching logic for each of your fields to their own method, like so:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private String _name;
    private String _address;
    private String _phoneNum;
    private Area _area;

    public boolean meetsCriteria(String name, String area, String phone, String category)
    {
        return matchesName(name) && matchesArea(area) && matchedPhone(phone) && matchesCategory(category);
    }

    private boolean matchesName(String name){
        return name.equals("") || name.equals(this._name) || this._name.indexOf(name) >= 0;
    }

    private boolean matchesArea(String area) {
        return areas.equals("") || this._aread.getArea().equals(area);
    }

    // create the missing methods yourself.
}
```